# Board shows high CPU Temperature, Core temperature normal - should I be worried?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, temperature, cpu-cooler

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I need to know.

For about two days now, my computer's coolers start howling at the least provocation (like starting eclipse, etc), though it never did before - even during my gaming hours. I opened the HWMonitor at bootup this morning and collected this data after some time.

[image: Temperature Measurement]

As you can see, the board list shows a very high max temperature for the CPU - however, the core temperature a bit lower is not close at it. Also, the current value for CPU never was that high when I looked at the monitor. Usually it's at 45°C or something.

I don't know much about hardware, so should I be worried here? Or is the temperature sensor broken?

What can I do to prevent my PC's coolers go off like crazy at normal work time? It always sounds like the hardware is about to melt and I don't dare starting a game, even.

(I usually only play WoW at mediocre graphics settings and it never was a problem before)

Comment: Unless this happens more then once I would just say its a glitch with CPUID.  Its normal for your CPU fan to spin faster if it has to work harder to keep things cool.  Eclipse can be a very CPU consuming program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are dangerously high, typically you'd see CPU temps peaking in the mid 70's range, anything beyond that is unsafe. Check your cooler and see if it hasn't come loose from the processor. Another possibility is that it may be clogged with dust, or that the fan atop the heatsink may have died.

Edit: Check your temps with another program, perhaps CoreTemp, and see if they match up.

Edit again: After looking a little more closely at that screenshot, it *is* pretty odd, but I'm leaning towards saying that the readings from the motherboard are anomalous. If the CPU sensor doesn't say it spiked to 90 deg. C, then it didn't. If there are any BIOS updates for your motherboard, you should think about applying them. It's possible that this is a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: CoreTemp gives me ~50°C as max after now some time of playing game.

Comment: Does the other program still reflect those high values? If so, it's either a buggy program, or there's some sort of temperature delta that needs to be figured out.

Comment: Both show ~50°C max for the CPU, it's only the Motherboard's temperature sensor that shows these ridiculous values for CPU.

Comment: The temperatures that come straight from the die of the CPU are authoritative (that's what CoreTemp shows). It seems that there's some sort of delta on the motherboard's temperature sensor readings that isn't being accounted for, for whatever reason.

Comment: Well I took your advise and updated the BIOS, not the desktop will not boot up at all and I don't know what to do, it just stands there humming, not starting.

Comment: How did you update the BIOS, did you use the utility from the manufacturer's website? Did you forcibly power off your PC at any point? At this point, you'll want to call the PC/motherboard vendor for support.

Comment: Well thank you for your help. I was foolish to believe I could upgrade it myself, support says the board is broken now - won't even boot when taken outside of the chassis ^^ Happens.